# Does $f(dx)$ have any meaning?

Tags: differential

Simple question, does a differential $dx$ have any meaning composed in a function $f$, such as $\sqrt{dx}$, where $f(x)\neq x$?

Comment: No. dx is a fundamentally different kind of object than x is.

Comment: Reminds me of $\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}=ds$, where one ends up with another differential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of. There is a dual concept to differentials, that of a "tangent vector", which is not unreasonable to think of as a kind of infinitesimal.

While $\mathrm{d}x$ is supposed to denote a differential, many unfortunately use the notation when they wish to speak of an infinitesimal. :(

Anyways, if $f$ is differentiable at a point $a$ and $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal, then we have

$$ f(a+\epsilon) = f(a) + f'(a) \epsilon $$

Note this is a literal equality and not merely an approximation, as this kind variety of infinitesimal satisfies $\epsilon^2 = 0$.

Comment: ...In smooth infinitesimal analysis. In Robinson-type nonstandard analysis this is not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

$$
f'(0)=\frac{f(0+dx) -f(0)}{dx}, \text{ so if }f(0)=0 \text{ then } f(dx)=f'(0)\,dx.
$$
However, I'm not sure I've ever seen this usage.

Comment: Urgh. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: [The horror, the horror...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNUr__-VZeQ). ("so"? Why "so"? Your "so" connects two unrelated statements.)

Answer (score 0):

When *f*(*x*) is the power function *xᵗ* for a certain *t∈*ℂ, the expression *f*(d*x*) makes perfect sense and is used quite often.  Here *x* is either 1-dimensional (=scalar; moreover, we should know which d*x*⸣s are “positive”, and which aren’t), or, in multi-dimensional case, d*x* means the *volume form*.

The key point is that in these cases, d*x* stands for **the linearization** of something else.  In particular, d*x* is an element of a 1-dimensional vector space *with orientation* — and for elements of such vector spaces, their powers [make perfect sense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958746/how-do-fractional-tensor-products-work) *as linear objects*.

These are called *t*-forms, or *t*-volume forms. (Google for [`"half-form" "volume form"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22half-form%22%20%22volume%20form%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&hl=en&num=100&pws=0) to see the most frequent examples.)

**Remark:** A similar thing can be done in complex case — but then one needs to *explicitly* carry the ambiguity of the sign of the square root of the derivative of coordinate change.  (As in [Metaplectic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaplectic_group).)

---

For example, when one writes *F*(*x*)d*x*, one means something which behaves “suitably” under changes of variable: when *x*=*x*(*y*), one can rewrite this as D*x*/D*y*·*F*(*x*(*y*))d*y* (with D*x*/D*y* being the determinant of the differential ∂*x*/∂*y*).  Likewise, when one writes *F*(*x*)(d*x*)ᵗ, the determinant is replaced by the *t*⸣th power of the determinant.

(Here either the determinant should be assumed positive, or one should “carry the burden of ambiguity of powers of arbitrary numbers”.)

---

Examples when this is useful:

- If you want to consider the *L*₂-space *on a manifold* *X*, it is natural to require that elements of this space to be half-forms: to have the form *F*(*x*)(d*x*)<sup>½</sup>.  Then ∫*FG* makes perfect sense even when you change variables.
- When one considers the Sturm–Liouville operator ‒∂²+*V*(*x*) on a 1-dimensional manifold, it may be considered as a self-adjoint operator acting from the space of ‒½-forms to the (dual) space of 1½-forms — but this needs the rewriting as ‒∂²+*V*(*x*)(d*x*)².  This does not survive *all* the coordinate changes: the degree=0 term can change to *V*(*x*)(d*x*)² + *S*(*x*)(d*x*)².  (What we achieved is that the degree=2 and degree=1 terms do not change under coordinate transforms.)

  However, one can recognize the formula for *S*(*x*) as the [*Schwarzian derivative*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzian_derivative) of the coordinate change; this simultaneously clarifies

  - the fact that Schwarzian derivatives should actually be written as *S*(*x*)(d*x*)²,
  - the geometric meaning of Schwarzian derivatives,
  - the fact that the operator above is preserved by the transformations for which the Schwarzian derivative vanishes (=projective transformations).
- The expression *S*(*x*)(d*x*)² above is an example of a [*quadratic differential*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_differential).  Such tensors are dual to vector fields; moreover, expressions *c*∂²+*V*(*x*)(d*x*)² with a scalar *c* can be recognized as elements of the dual vector space to the [*Virasoro algebra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virasoro_algebra) (which is a 1-dimensional extension to the Lie algebra of vector fields) — so they “govern” the representation theory of this Lie algebra.
- Another topic governed by quadratic differentials is the [*Teichmüller space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichm%C3%BCller_space).
- modular forms of weight 2*k* should be written as *F*(*z*)(d*z*)ᵏ.  For example, [η(*z*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form#The_modular_discriminant) has weight ½, so in some contexts it is easier to work with η(*z*)(d*z*)<sup>¼</sup> instead.

Answer (score -2):

Since $dx=\Delta x$, we may view $f(dx)$ as $f(\Delta x)$.

Comment: [WAT](https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2727748211/c3d0981ae770f926eedf4eda7505b006.jpeg)

Comment: The notion that $dx=\Delta x$, if it makes any sense, holds only in very limited contexts.  Yes, lots of calculus textbooks say that.  Maybe that's evidence against it.

Comment: . . . or, rather, let me put it this way: I hope I have never condoned the practice of considering $dx$ to be the same thing as $\Delta x$. Think of what that implies about $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$.  It would mean that $f(x)\,\Delta x$ is within the scope of the integral sign.  That is absurd. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Hola_Mundo's question AND answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876310/meaning-behind-differentials/876503#876503) seems to make sense to me and (s)he just defines $dx = \Delta x$. Why does this not work?

Comment: Because $\Delta x$ is supposed to be a finite change in $x$ and $dx$ is supposed to be an infinitesimal.

Comment: It does not do what we want when we say $\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to 0}\dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \dfrac{dy}{dx}$, nor when we say $\displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$, nor when, as a means of proving that $\sin'=\cos$ we say that the infinitely small arc of a circle of length $dx$ moves the point $(\cos x,\sin x)$ to the point $(\cos(x+dx),\sin(x+dx))$ and consider that arc to be a straight line at right angles to the radius from $(0,0)$ to $(\cos x,\sin x)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to 0}\dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ would converge exactly to $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ by definition.  What else do we want it to do?  In $\displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$, it's defined the same way as a Riemann integral.  And I would never try to prove $\sin(x) = \cos(x)$ by evaluating differentials or arclength by looking at $(\cos(x +dx),\ \sin(x+dx))$.  At least not in standard analysis.  Are you considering this from the viewpoint of non-standard analysis?